# How to create documents if they don't exist based on a timsteamp in firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a challenage, that I don't know how to realize. Becuase of that, I can't provide any code.
I want to track training sets (weights, repeats) related to a timestamp.

```
[
    {
        weights: 15,
        repeats: 10,
        training_date: firebase.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    },
    {
        weights: 15,
        repeats: 9,
        training_date: firebase.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    },
    {
        weights: 12,
        repeats: 10,
        training_date: firebase.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    },
]
```

This could be a training of 3 sets. When I train on another day, the timestamp (Y.m.d) changes. With that logic I want to group training sets to training set groups and later query that groups.

As I am coming from MySQL this challenge is tough for me.
I don't know how to realize that logic.

I thought about adding documents with the timestamp (Y.m.d) as id and sub collections. But I don't know how the code will look like to create an document or append to the document's collection if the id already exists (React code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not using dates as document IDs.  It will only cause problems going forward.  I would be far better to accept the random ID provided by Firestore, and put the date in a field of the document.  This is shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).  Then you can use that date in a query against the collection to find all trainings on that date.

`add()` will provide that random ID for you:

```
firestore.collection("your-collection").add({
    weights: 15,
    repeats: 10,
    training_date: "YYYYMMDD"
})
```

See that the date is a formatted string, as timestamps represent a *point in time to nanosecond precision* rather than a date as a whole.  Note also the date format puts years first in the format.

You can now find all the trainings on a certain date:

```
firestore.collection("your-collection").where("training_date", ==, "20200423")
```

And you can then sort chronologically:

```
firestore.collection("your-collection").orderBy("training_date")
```

Comment: Everything is working but when I use orderBy() I don't get any data. When I remove it, everything is there

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a new question that describes in more detail what isn't working the way you expect, along with your code and data.